# Best of PPCG 2015 — Call for Categories

Tags: discussion, best-of

At the end of each year, our <s>nemesis</s> friendly neighbours at Code Review vote for the best questions and answers from that year. I think that is a great tradition we should <s>steal</s> adopt here as well, because it allows us to showcase some of the amazing content we've created and potentially reward the authors.

2015 has already ended, but I don't see a problem with determining the winners a few weeks into the new year.

To start, we need categories. That's what this post is for! Each answer should contain a category for a challenge or answer to be rewarded. The top-voted categories will then receive separate nomination posts to find the actual winners. (I don't want to put a fixed number of categories here, because I can't anticipate how many proposals we'll get. Something between 5 and 10 seems reasonable.)

Winners will be rewarded with bounties where applicable (that is, for answer categories). For question categories I'm happy to take suggestions for rewards. Maybe our supreme challenge writers like Calvin's Hobbies and Zgarb might volunteer to post a challenge related to the author?

If you're willing to reward the winner of a category yourself (by offering your own rep for the bounty), please mention that in the category proposal.

Comment: So now we know that you visit Code Review *throws tomato*.

Comment: How would awarding a bounty for the winner of a category work? AIUI there aren't bounties on meta. I suppose that for answer categories the bounty could go directly to the answer, but for question categories?

Comment: @PeterTaylor That's what I meant. Winning answers will get bounties. For winning challenges we need to sort out something else.

Comment: @Fatalize Truth is, I do, but only their meta [to check this question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2538/54789).

Comment: To some extent, even without a reward, a winner is likely to see more views and votes on their question than otherwise. I still like the idea of thinking up ways to reward questions too though.

Comment: It just occurred to me that it might make more sense for people to offer their rep for bounties independently of specific categories in case they win those categories themselves. So anyone who is willing to give up some of their rep for this, let me know, and we'll sort out how we split up the categories once we have the winners.

Comment: @MartinBüttner I wouldn't worry too much about that. If I offer 50 rep as a reward for thingiest answer, and then my answer wins, I get the same rep in both of the following cases: 1. I give my 50 rep elsewhere and receive someone else's 50 rep for my answer, or 2. We do nothing (the award is just not given, so I don't gain 50 but also don't lose 50). I still get the prestige of being announced thingiest answer here.

Comment: @trichoplax That's a good point. It would probably still be fairer to the generous people offering their rep if the bounties were split up evenly between them at the end.

Comment: Also, actually giving the bounties would have the additional effect of drawing attention to that answer for 7 days.

Comment: The drawing attention point is a good one - that changes my mind.

Comment: Sounds like we need to decide how rep will be split between awards too. Can a generous donor choose for 500 to go to just one award that they consider more important, or will it end up split evenly between all the awards?

Comment: @trichoplax ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ that's why I think it would be simpler to just get a pool of people who want to offer their rep and work it out between those people in chat.

Comment: That works... :)

Comment: Are we allowed to have awards for people that are not specific to a particular challenge or question? I see some of Ampora's suggestions are in that category.

Comment: @geokavel sure, why not, as long as the category is somehow related to the content produced by that user.

Answer (score 31):

**Educational:** Best answer containing interesting and/or deep mathematical (or other) material.

*I will offer a 200 reputation bounty for the winner of this category.*

Comment: Bet you the winner will be xnor/Peter Taylor

Comment: @RikerW Probably, or Dennis. Though my [work on pies](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60286/45941) would also be in the running :P

Comment: @RikerW I'm putting my money on Ell.

Comment: @MartinBüttner wat?

Answer (score 30):

**Less is more:** Best challenge with a simple but novel problem and a concise and clear spec.

Answer (score 27):

## Most Above-and-Beyond Answer

Every once and a while, an answer takes the challenge to the extreme.  This prize will be awarded to an answer which went far beyond the expectations of the challenge. This could include

- a code golf answer that brute-forced/proved the shortest program in some language
- a graphical-output popcon answer of extreme size and quality
- a KOTH answer of high complexity which absolutely dominated the competition

Comment: I will offer a 100 reputation bounty for the winner of this category.

Comment: I've already got a particular answer of Martin's in mind...

Answer (score 25):

**Best Newcomer (challenge)**: Best challenge by a user who had not posted a challenge before 2015 (this is basically equivalent to **Best Newcomer** but for challenges instead of answers).

Comment: I'll offer to create a challenge that features the winner of this category in some way (as bounties can't be awarded to challenges).

Comment: As suggested in chat, we might want to rename the "best newcomer" categories to "Rookie of the Year".

Answer (score 22):

**Labour of love:** for a great challenge that took immense amounts of preparation on the part of the challenge author.

Comment: Labour of love?

Comment: @trichoplax thank you, I'm going with that.

Comment: I assume such thing like **Best test case collection in a question** not worth a separate award and will be included in this, right?

Comment: @manatwork I'd say make a separate answer and let the votes decide. I don't think good test cases necessarily take a lot of effort.

Comment: @manatwork Peter added it as a separate category

Comment: To make the bounty prizes even more disproportionate, I'm up for putting 500 on the winner of this category (or some other category if this one fails to make it)

Comment: @Sp3000 Where would you award the bounty? Or do you mean you'd put the bounty up for an answer to that challenge?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Assuming the author has answered something I was hoping to award it to an answer they wrote, but is that a bad idea?

Comment: @Sp3000 I don't think it's a great idea unless that answer is deserving 500 rep in itself (although of course, there's nothing stopping you from doing it anyway). That said, I think a bounty for an answer to that challenge is also a reward for the challenge author, because it draws some more attention (and probably upvotes) to that challenge, as well as new answers (hopefully).

Answer (score 22):

**Team Effort:** Answer that involved the cooperation of many people.

Answer (score 20):

**Right tool:** Best answer using a special ability of a language.

Comment: I'd support this if "best" was clarified to mean most interesting or imaginative or clever, not raw golfing effectiveness.

Answer (score 20):

## Showcase of Most Promising New Golfing Language

There seem to be quite a few of these new languages that have popped up in the last year.

Answer (score 18):

**Persistent:** Best answer where a user has dramatically improved his/her original answer, sometimes multiple times in a row.

Comment: Crossed out 44 is still 44 :(

Answer (score 17):

**Don't push me out of the box!**
An answer that uses a very clever algorithm that nobody had thought of before.

Answer (score 16):

**Best Newcomer (answer):** Best answer by a user who had not posted an answer before 2015. (Idea taken from Code Review.)

Comment: Just to avoid ambiguity, the current wording means a prolific 2014 question asker who posts their first answer in 2015 would be eligible for nomination. I don't see this as a bad thing.

Comment: @trichoplax I think that's totally fine (same for the opposite cateogory).

Answer (score 14):

**Rookie of the year**

The winner of this category will have regularly posted high-quality questions and/or answers since they joined the site, which must have occurred in 2015.

---

As a newcomer myself, I would be willing to offer a 100-rep bounty to an answer that the winner of this award as posted.

Comment: I'm not sure this adds much to the separate challenge/answer newcomer categories.

Comment: I would think that the difference between them is that the previous "Newcomer" categories are for specific questions/answers; this one is for someone who posts *many* high-quality questions/answers.

Comment: Oh right, I had sort of thought of those as user-specific rather than post-specific as well, but you're right they are more about posts. In that case, I definitely support this.

Comment: Thanks @TimmyD for the better title idea.

Answer (score 14):

**Silver lining**: Answer with the most clever <s>ab</s>use of an interpreter <s>bug</s> undocumented feature.

Answer (score 14):

**Emperor of the Hill:** Best KotH in terms of planning, clear specification, and novelty.

Comment: "King of the Hill King"...

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yup.

Comment: Emperor of the Hill?

Answer (score 13):

## Against the odds

Best answer in a non-golfing language that is as short or shorter than golfing-language answers.  Defining "golfing" vs "non-golfing" language may be tricky in some cases, but I think its clear in most cases.

Comment: Similar to http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7925/8478

Comment: I'd be sad if this went to an answer that won simply by the language having the perfect built-in to solve the challenge. Can that be ruled out?

Comment: Are there any? Beating Pyth with CJam is an achievement, but I can't think of any examples of beating either with C or Python.

Comment: @PeterTaylor [A trivial example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60733/count-the-bytes-of-a-program/60740#60740).  This may well be disqualified on the grounds that xnor lays out.  I think there are others though.

Answer (score 13):

### It's Alive

Best answer in a difficult to program in language, such as Malbolge, Hexagony, or Fission.

*I will offer a 200 rep bounty for this category*

Comment: Wow, Hexagony and Fission in one sentence with Malbolge. :D

Comment: Looking at you Funciton...

Comment: I was thinking Shakespeare...

Answer (score 11):

#### Phoenix

Most dramatic improvement in a question. For example, a question that was closed and then edited to become hugely successful.

Comment: Note that sometimes questions get closed for good reasons, reopened when they shouldn't be, then mega-upvoted because they end up in the HNQ. That may be viewed as success when in fact it's a detriment to the overall quality of the site.

Comment: @AlexA. this is very true. I wouldn't want a question to be awarded this based purely on a report being run, but I'd still like to see it awarded as a result of being nominated and discussed on meta.

Comment: (Note that being previously closed need not be a prerequisite for being nominated for this award.)

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.

Comment: @AlexA. an obvious nomination for this would be http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24401/15599 (though it's over a year old.) I'm pretty sure the question enhances the site, though the original version was so broad that the final, narrower version is essentially a different question (though just a few words were changed.) Popcons are high risk, so we'd surely see a lot of them in this category.

Answer (score 11):

**Abusive:** An answer that cleverly uses a certain feature of the given language in a way that was clearly not intended.

@ThomasKwa mentioned that this obviously only applies for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). Does it? I cannot think of any other type of challenge right now, but if there is one, I'd like to leave it open for that one too.

Comment: Does this differ from [silver lining](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7929/20283) in that it abuses a feature rather than a bug? (If so, +1 to both)

Comment: I had "official" features in mind: Everything should work the way it is documented, but the usage of a certain feature is not what it was intended for. Fictional example: Solving a system of equations using a sound processing function.

Comment: I think this should mention something about being used in golfing.

Comment: I don't see why popcons or CnRs can't have good instances of language abuse, so I'm up for the "keep it open" option.

Answer (score 11):

**Trickiest**: The answer that uses the most subtle technique(s) to golf code.

Ideally, the trick(s) should be hard for an experienced use of the language to spot, and lead to the shortest code in that language.

The tricks may be using language features as intended - what's important is that they are unintuitive.

*I will offer a 200 rep bounty for this category*

Comment: I'll offer 100 of my own rep.

Answer (score 11):

### Best answer to a difficult challenge

Some [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) questions on this site are difficult programming challenges even without the golfing aspect. When golfing a challenge where one does not see an immediate, clear path to the solution to start with, one must first pick an approach, write a solution, and then continuously consider new approaches while golfing it down.

This award will go to an answer which, due to the difficulty of the challenge, has great *necessary* complexity—and is excellently golfed. Both the approach used and micro-optimization will be considered.

To give an idea of the length, the answer should be about 250+ bytes of non-data code in languages like Python, or about 60+ bytes in a golfing language like Pyth—but, of course, to a challenge in which an inexpert golfer's solution wouldn't be anywhere near that short. Languages designed to be long/difficult to program in most likely not be considered.

A better title is appreciated.

I'll offer *350 rep* to the winner.

I think this is sufficiently different from [Most Above-and-Beyond Answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7921/39328).

Answer (score 10):

### Green Jersey

For the question with the best set of test cases. As a minimum requirement they should cover corner cases and unintuitive cases, and ideally they should do so elegantly.

---

I did think about a name invoking the Ashes, but a cricket reference is probably too obscure for people from non-cricket-playing countries. I also considered something along the lines of the idiom "the proof is in the pudding". The current WIP title combines the green of a successfully passed test suite with a Tour de France reference.

Comment: The title makes me thing of the Master's Tournament's green jacket, from golf.

Answer (score 9):

**Most Impractical**: Best answer where in the interest of saving characters, the runtime will encounter [Universe heat-death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe#Big_Freeze_or_heat_death) issues, or requires more storage space than [atoms available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observable_universe#Matter_content).

Answer (score 9):

**Pro tip:** best answer to any *general* [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) question. That is, candidates should be drawn from "Tips for golfing in X" questions (as opposed to specific "how do I shorten this piece of code" questions).

Comment: [238 candidates](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/420263/tips-answers) with the restriction.

Comment: I petition to change the name to "Tip Top" or some variation thereof.

Comment: *Pro tip* is a more Internetty name.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I like that too. Currently it doesn't look like this one is gonna make the top 10 though.

Answer (score 9):

**Meta World Peace:** For the person who has done the most to advance the development of this site through contributions (questions and/or answers) to Meta.

Answer (score 8):

**Jack of all trades**

User who posts answers with detailed explanations in many languages, allowing those not versed in the language to understand what is going on

Comment: That user being Martin Büttner? :P

Answer (score 8):

## Golden Oldie

Best answer in a language that has been around for 40 years or more.

Comment: The language would be most likely APL.

Comment: @jimmy23013 possibly.  Others that immediately spring to mind in no particular order: c, dc, cobol, sed

Answer (score 8):

**Necromancer:** similar but not identical to the badge of the same name. Best answer posted in 2015 to a challenge from before 2014.

(The gap of a full year is to exclude answers to challenges which were posted just before New Year's and answered just after it.)

Since almost all tips answers fall into this category, the [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips) tag is excluded from this. [I have added a separate category for those.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7961/8478)

Comment: The gap required for the badge is just 60 days. I think it would be an improvement to follow the badge, so that an answer in August to a question in February would still count. I haven't done a data.SE query, but I suspect that opening it up like that would increase the number of candidates from very few to a reasonable number.

Comment: @PeterTaylor There were 296 Necromancers awarded in 2015. There would be additional candidates for this category that never reached a score of 5. I think that's a lot more candidates than we need. And I figured with the absolute date requirements it would be easier to find possible candidates. (I'm also happy to change the name to avoid confusion if you've got a better idea.)

Comment: (And I suppose votes on either your or my comment will show whether people would rather have a 60-day limit or a 1-year limit.)

Comment: Your criterion gives [756 results] before filtering out tips.

Comment: @PeterTaylor And after? ;)

Comment: [648](http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/420062)

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think that's more than enough?

Comment: Yes. If we can assume that anything worthwhile would be on at least +2, that reduces it to 160 answers to look at, which is still quite a lot, but hopefully that won't be necessary because people will self-nominate.

Comment: If you don't like the name you could change it to Palaeontologist or maybe Archaeologist.

Answer (score 7):

**Graduate of the Peter Taylor academy:** For a highly-rated question that went through many revisions in Sandbox.

Comment: IMO [Labor of Love](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7932/39328) is better.

Comment: @Thomas I just think we're trying to encourage certain behaviors, and using the Sandbox is one of them.

Comment: That's a good point. If there were a way to award users who provide feedback on the Sandbox, I'd definitely do that.

Comment: @ThomasKwa you could suggest that as another category...

Comment: @trichoplax the problem is the title of this answer already gives a suggestion of who would win.

Comment: @geokavel I agree - and I think it would be well deserved :)

Comment: I love the title on this

Answer (score 5):

## Per-language awards

[These](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26648074#26648074) are the most commonly used languages on PPCG in 2015. The top 9:

- Python: 1946 answers
- Javascript: 1285
- CJam: 1164
- Pyth: 1037
- Ruby: 648
- Perl: 618
- Haskell: 535
- C: 497
- Mathematica: 483

Each language has unique golfing tricks. Therefore, I will give *100 rep* for the best overall Python answer, and *50 rep* for the best overall answer in each of the other eight languages. Answers should be judged based on quality, effort, and the showcase of a language's features. This award is not restricted to [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf): answers to every type of challenge are eligible.

This complements [Jack of All Trades](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7923/39328).

Answer (score 4):

#### Best title

Borrowed from the Code Review categories.

"Best" can be measured as a combination of things:

- Descriptive
- Intriguing
- Funny
- Any more we can think of...

Comment: Oops, well it was a new one so it won't be missed.

Comment: I've already got a challenge in mind

Comment: That makes 2 of you...

Comment: "Can be taken out of context"

Answer (score 3):

**Tiger Woods**: Answer with the best, most impressive golfing.

*If you feel this  category is unnecessary/overlaps with others please upvote Martin's comment.*

Comment: Seems to overlap with http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7913/8478 and http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7921/8478. (Especially the former.)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I disagree. I've seen impressive golfs that were posted in one fell swoop, and that should be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

### Best use of a Stack Snippet

Question or answer which demonstrated the best use of a stack snippet.

Answer (score 2):

**Win with a longwinded language**

Win with a language such as Java, beating out shorter languages.

*Needs some better criteria.*

Comment: This applies only to code golf answers, I assume?

Comment: @MartinBüttner Yes, but a different category might be for [tag:popularity-contest].

Comment: Seems like there would be overlap with [Right Tool](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7915/42963)

Comment: @TimmyD Possibly. I might change it to in a popularity contest.  That might be better.

Comment: I think this is liable to go to an answer that just uses the perfect built-in of the longwinded language. I'd find that pretty disappointing, since it's more about knowing that built-in exists and being first to post, rather than doing something creative.

Comment: @xnor, assuming there are any candidates at all.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think you're right. Even when someone does something clever that beats out golfing langs for the moment, others port the methods into golfing langs.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily need to be a code-golf competition ... http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/58760/42963

Answer (score 1):

**Good Samaritan:** The person who has contributed the most to other people's answers.

Comment: I expect that there are a few people with more than 100 contributions over the year, and evaluating which of them has made the most overall contribution would require a *lot* of effort.

Answer (score 1):

**Philanthropist:** The person who has given away the most reputation in bounties this year.

Comment: *begins offering bounties*

Comment: you can't do that now; it's 2016.

Comment: @ThomasKwa I'm planning ahead.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good fit as it doesn't necessarily reward great content.

Comment: I agree with Martin; plus this is objective.

Answer (score 1):

## Most Ripped-Off Idea

Often somebody has a very clever idea or workaround to a standard technique. This idea – if clever enough – will most likely be <s>copied</s> adopted by a lot of other answerers by simply applying it to their language.

---

### Example

The [Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/66675/41859) to [Advance Happy New Year, 2016!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/66656/41859) is a very good example, as *nearly every* other answer adopted the used technique, which led to massive byte reduction in almost every language.

Comment: This will probably overlap significantly with [this category](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7934/8478) (at least that Mathematica answer is what I was going to nominate for that category).

Comment: @MartinBüttner Ah, true that. I completely overlooked that category. It's strongly related. Funny though, that we both have the same answer in mind. :)

Comment: This isn't quite "FGITW on a question which hit HNQ", but it's close.

Comment: The proposal in general.

Answer (score -1):

#### Flypaper

Question that has attracted the largest number of first time answers.

That is, the question that has brought the largest number of newcomers to the site.

---

*We'd need to settle on the finer details of the rules:*

- *First time answers only count from users who then went on to post at least one more net positively voted question/answer.*
- *First time answers only count if they are net positively voted and not deleted.*

Comment: I think the two additional requirements you mention would probably be a good idea for this one so that it actually measures "number of users drawn who provide high-quality content".

Comment: This is too correlated with "won the HNQ lottery" for my taste. And the question poster probably already got a buttload of rep for it.

Comment: @xnor That's why I added the extra conditions. Are there any others you'd add to reduce this effect?

Comment: I'm not too worried about questions that already have lots of rep being recognised - it can be a smaller award to reflect that if you like but I still think they are worth celebrating...

Comment: @trichoplax I don't think adding conditions like that saves it because HNQ is such a large multiplier. Even with an ideal definition of "good activity", I think there's too much luck in timing and network effects.

Comment: @xnor I do think that even awards that have objective conditions like "largest" or "highest" should still be decided by discussion on meta. If the question that most fits the condition is considered a poor example then another can be chosen instead.

Answer (score -4):

**Most Difficult**:  This challenge got only a few (or no) answers because of its incredible difficulty.

Comment: Challenges of *incredible difficulty* should be closed as too broad, not rewarded.

Comment: That's totally not true.  We have many "really tough" challenges that are totally on topic.  Consider the [Build a game of Tetris using Game of Life](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life) challenge.  Its certainly not too broad, but is *really* hard.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't agree at all. If a challenge is too difficult to get any answers, neither active nor passive members benefit from it. This particular challenge isn't self-contained and doesn't have a winning criterion other than *first person to create a demonstrably working example*. I'm not even convinced it should remain open.

Answer (score -6):

**Class clown:** An answer that made everyone guffaw when they first read/understood it.

*Note that this should probably only apply to answers that also followed the rules of the challenge to which they were posted, as wilfully misinterpreting rules is no longer funny.*

Answer (score -13):

**Justified:** The answer with the most hilarious [justification why a certain task needs to be solved in as few bytes as possible.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5856/24877)

Now I need just need to add more text in order to avoid this answer to be converted to a comment because it was considered a *trivial answer*.

Comment: I'd rather not encourage that practice any further. :/

Comment: @MartinBüttner Why do you dislike it?

Comment: @Mego it was funny when the justifications still made remotely sense. At this point it just clutters up the specs.

Comment: Independent of this suggestion here: Are 'negative awards' something you generally do not want to here?

Comment: @flawr Considering how you described them as "negative", probably not.